# Strange bug happened with rails/git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, archlinux, ext4

I've experienced a strange bug with rails 3.2 / git.

In development mode, classes was not reloaded between requests (controllers, models, helpers) but views work.

I've searched a long time in unmodified configuration (application.rb, development.rb...) without success, I have to reload Thin to show changes.

So I've decided to create a new branch and revert commit by commit (I was thinking a bad updated/integration gem) and the code reload properly to the last commit !

Back to the master branch, code is reloaded properly between requests without any code change.

I'm running on Archlinux, ruby 1.9.3p194 (rvm), postgresql 9.1.4, git 1.7.11.1, ext4 FS tuned (UUID=ac74249f-84de-40d0-8b14-eb494983cfda /home ext4 defaults,noatime,data=writeback,barrier=0,nobh,errors=remount-ro 0 1)

What do you think about that ?

---

This bug never came back and very difficult to reproduce. I can't accept uncertain answers.

Comment: I don't know enough rails to debug your problem, but "revert commit by commit" makes me sad. [Look up](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git) `git bisect`. [It'll change your life.](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git)

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem has nothing to do with GIT, only rails.

Try to put in your config/environments/development.rb:

```
  config.cache_classes = false
```

That's rails configuration which tells it to reload classes (such as models or controllers) between requests.

Just to be sure, run rails server with: `RAILS_ENV=development rails s`

Comment: I'm sure at 100% this is not a rails issue because environment configuration was untouched and the problem disappears after creating a new git branch. And during the issue, the environment was well in development

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is the `noatime` option in the fstab. How should rails now that the file has changed if the timestamp is not touched. You could try to remove the option.